# postgres in condition with like

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT first_name FROM "profiles" where first_name in ('one','Ankita')
```

I would like to run above query in such manner.

```
SELECT first_name FROM "profiles" where first_name in ('on%','Ank%')
```

Is it possible? if yes then it should return first_name start with 'on' and 'An'.

Comment: Can you cocatenate them with '|' characters between them?  That would seem to work without requiring an 'in' clause, and would probably be more efficient.

Comment: @DylanB: But `|` doesn't mean anything special with LIKE, you'd have to switch to [SIMILAR TO or a regex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) and that might over complicate things (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ANY with an array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html):

> **9.23.3. ANY/SOME (array)**
>
> ```
> expression operator ANY (array expression)
> expression operator SOME (array expression)
> ```
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given **operator**, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of `ANY` is "true" if any true result is obtained. The result is "false" if no true result is found (including the case where the array has zero elements).

So you can say things like:

```
select first_name
from profiles
where first_name like any (array['on%', 'Ank%'])
```

You could also use [a regex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) instead of LIKE:

```
first_name ~  '^(on|Ank)'  -- Case sensitive
first_name ~* '^(on|Ank)' -- Case insensitive
```

Comment: In fact, PostgreSQL transforms `IN (...)` into `= ANY (...)` internally.

Comment: @CraigRinger: A transformation I've seen in my SQL schema dumps. This reminds me a bit of some ["stupid ORMs!"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20831395/479863) ranting we've done lately :)

Comment: `<operator> ANY (...)` is SQL standard syntax too, so that particular transformation wouldn't be cause for complaint, `= ANY (...)` is just as good as `IN (...)`. As for "stupid ORMs" - yep, but "stupid !@# SQL" too, the standard is to blame for some of the portability issues (failure to standardize obvious things like `OFFSET` / `LIMIT` for over a decade, imagining new and insane syntax for every new feature). As are implementors, of course.